# How to retrieve multiple data from Firebase database?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Here is the piece of code that I have written but it returns the whole schema.

```
mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("/News");
    mTitle = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.title_view);

    mDatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            String title=dataSnapshot.getValue().toString();;
            mTitle.setText(title);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {}
    });
```

[image]

Comment: what do you want to do?

Comment: I'm trying to retrieve desc & title and display them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To solve this, simply use the following lines of code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference newsRef = rootRef.child("News");
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String desc = ds.child("desc").getValue(String.class);
            String title = ds.child("title").getValue(String.class);
            Log.d(TAG, desc + " / " + title);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.d(TAG, databaseError.getMessage());
    }
};
newsRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

The output in your logcat will be:

```
desc1 / title1
desc2 / title2
```

Answer (score 1):

```
use this method 
//-----------------//
private void getDataFrom() {

            String userId = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();

            DatabaseReference mCustomerDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child("1");

            mCustomerDatabase.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    if (dataSnapshot.exists() && dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount() > 0) {
                        Map<String, Object> map = (Map<String, Object>) dataSnapshot.getValue();
                        if (map.get("title") != null) {
                            customer_name = map.get("title").toString();
                            Log.i("customer_name",String.valueOf(customer_name));

                        }

                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                }
            });
        }
```

Comment: if you are facing any problem fetch data from firebase database. so please let me know. Thank You

Answer (score 0):

### this is how i'm getting my all firebase data

```
     DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    DatabaseReference db = databaseReference.child("Customers");
            arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
            db.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                    for(DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren())
                    {

                          arrayList.add(snapshot.getValue(Customer_Details2.class));
                    }



                    checkUpdate();
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
```